# Server API for multiple devices

Tags: node.js, server, backend

I have done a website in Nodejs and Expressjs and a question struck me. My front-end and back-end are integrated together, meaning I needed to use routes and such to direct users and show the web page. However, if I want to make a mobile app and would like to access the same server and same database, how would I do it because my knowledge right now is limited to back-end and front-end much be developed together since I can't really separate out the front-end HTML stuffs from my Nodejs set-up.

I think it is an easy question but a confusing one to a newbie like me.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this in my experience is to build a REST API, which you can still do using Express if you're comfortable with that.  You would probably mount a separate Express app on some other url (https://api.example.com/ or https://example.com/api), for example.  Ideally, you would have done this first, and then had your web site hit that API as well, but since you didn't not a big deal.  If your code is appropriately modularized, then all you should really have to rewrite is a thin layer of controller code (for example to `res.send()` rather than `res.render()`).